# Insert to postgresql 9.1 seems to work but does nothing (QT postgres driver)

Tags: database, qt, insert, postgresql-9.1

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1, Qt 4.8.4 and have properly configured postgresql driver for qt and my problem is the next:

I have coded a little program to test the database I need to use and as far as it gets the connection between the program and the database works fine cause the .open() method does not return an error but when I try to insert something into a table it just doesn't do it. No error appears neither warning, nothing. It just happens nothing cause when I see the DB in the terminal it's the same as before...

What is happening? By the way I use Ubuntu 12.06 64 bits and my code is as follows (just omitted the QT Widget code), Thanks! :

```
//Respective headers

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");

    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("database");
    db.setUserName("user");
    db.setPassword("somepass");

    if(!db.open())
    {
        cout << "Database cannot be opened";
    }

                   //Unitl here no errors

QString consulta = "Insert into productos values ('25','25','25)";


    //db.transaction();

    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.prepare(consulta);     //Here tried to pass directly the string with same results
    query.exec();                //Even omitted .prepare but nothing
    query.finish();


    cout << "Rows affected: " << query.numRowsAffected();
  //  db.commit();

//Finishes ok but no errors

}
```

Which one is the correct way of doing this? thanks

PD.- Database's not the problem, query directly in psql runs well

Comment: Why is `db.commit();` commented out? What happens if it is not commented out?

Comment: `query.exec()` return `true` if succed and `false` otherwise, check this value and watch `query.lastError()` if it is `false`

Comment: Another debug idea (for future purposes, now your error is clear) is to copypaste query string to pgadmin or some oter tool and try to execute it there, errors in queries are often can be easily found that way.

Comment: *Always* check for and handle errors. Remember, Qt doesn't generally throw exceptions, you need to explicitly check for error returns.

Comment: actually I do ever query first in the psql console and the try it on code but cause im unfamiliar with qt im having problems knowing how it manage data types
db.commit() its commented cause it was only for debugging purpose, inherited in the method call is db.transacction() and db.commit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QString consulta = "Insert into productos values ('25','25','25)";`
You forgotten `'` in last value
(Should be `QString consulta = "Insert into productos values ('25','25','25')";`)